# scalaj Http header not being recognized

Tags: scala, scalaj-http

I'm trying to invoke an API using scalaj. I need to have a Authorization as type Bearer Token passed with the request. When I try to execute this API using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) as well as curl, I'm able to get a valid response.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <some auth token>" -H 'Accept: application/json' <some url>
```

But when I try to run it using the scalaj library, it fails to run, giving me `401: Not Authorized`. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```scala
val response = Http("https://<my url>")
            .headers(Seq("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + authToken)))
            .asString
            .body
```

(PS. `authToken` is defined and valid, no doubts there)

Why I'm trying to have Bearer Token is because its mentioned in the docs:

Every request must include the Authorization HTTP header with the value Bearer [access_token]. An access token can be obtained with the /auth/tokens endpoint, and it is used by Product XYZ to identify who you are. Product XYZ negotiates SSL connections using the TLS v1.2 protocol.

Comment: Same error response. Didnt work

Comment: How did you solve this plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `Accept` header as well:

```
val response = Http("https://<my url>")
        .headers(Seq("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + authToken), "Accept" -> "application/json"))
        .asString
        .body
```

Maybe the API requires that specific header.